# Is it possible to get my SWT application to run anywhere just by adding the SWT binaries to the Java Build Path in Eclipse?

Tags: java, swt

I made an SWT application using WindowBuilder in Eclipse. I exported the project as a runnable Jar File on Windows 10, then transferred the file to  my Macosx machine, and I received this error,

```
$ java -jar Downloads/SWTApplication.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    no swt-win32-4926r21 in java.library.path
    no swt-win32 in java.library.path
    Can't load library: /Users/myhomefolder/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-win32-4926r21.jnilib
    Can't load library: /Users/myhomefolder/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-win32.jnilib

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:143)
    at MainWindow.open(MainWindow.java:58)
    at MainWindow.main(MainWindow.java:47)
```

I tried adding both the windows and mac versions of swt.jar file to the Java Build Path in Eclipse, and it did not work. Is there a way to get it to work just by adding the SWTs to the Java Build Path? Tell me if there are more steps to this process if there is.

I expected the program to run on my Mac machine, just like when I double click the Jar File on my Windows Machine, but it returned the error above.

Please bear with me since I'm relatively new to Java and SWT.

Comment: Checkout https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SWT/article.html#exercise_swtproject

Comment: Here from log its looks like you application is searching SWT windows library on your mac os. Please use correct library .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load SWT library on Windows 32-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962165/could-not-load-swt-library-on-windows-32-bit)

Comment: You really need to build a separate version for each platform with the correct SWT for the platform. For example Eclipse is just a really large SWT app and has separate builds for each platform.

Comment: Also note that the swt.jar itself is different for each platform.

Comment: I tried following [this](https://www.chrisnewland.com/select-correct-swt-jar-for-your-os-and-jvm-at-runtime-191) website's instruction, but it didn't work. Can I delete this question and make a new one regarding this website?

Comment: The code on that website won't work on modern versions of Java because of changes to the system class loader.

Comment: Is there a way I can still get my application to run anywhere?